# Слово "покой" в значении "помещение"

Tags: семантика

Слово "покои" означает "комнаты, внутренние помещения". А употребляется ли это слово в единственном числе в том же значении?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, в единственном числе оно употребляется только в словосочетании ***приёмный покой*** (помещение для приёма больных, поступающих в больницу — [Грамота](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9&all=x)).